# Store uploaded images securely

Tags: php, mysql, security, sensitive-data

Im developing some server side code with PHP/MYSQL which requires user authentification.

When a user creates a new account I do all the standard hash+salt stuff to store the hash in the database but i dont know what to do with the scaned ID they need to upload.

I mean, if you create an account, part of your personal data (First Name, Last Name, Address, ... ) is a scaned copy (image) of a physical ID card (Driver License, ...) and im concerned on how should I properly handle this sensitive images.

I would appreciate if you guys can point me in the right direction or give me some hints.

Thank you for your time!

EDIT:

Wow, you guys are awesome and fast!

The storage of the IDs is mandatory, I wish i can workarround somehow but I cant.

I will give access throught software as you suggest and try to delete and store in CD's or something like that as you suggested.

I was thinking about scrambling the binary data with some crypto but not sure if its a good idea.

Comment: There's no danger if you simply handle the files correctly. I would simply store them outside the web-root. You don't automatically get security simply because you store them in a database.

Comment: always rename the stored files with as an md5 string (or something). so they can't access the uploaded filename anymore. store the original name into the dbase with the encrypted name.
to be sure mangle it trough the imagecreate(). and check mime types (not bullet proof!)

Comment: @RonnieJespersen: There is no such thing as "*no danger*".  Security can only ever make a goal *more difficult* for an attacker to accomplish—nothing is impenetrable.  The best that one can *ever* hope to achieve is to make a goal so difficult to accomplish that the attackers about whom one is concerned deplete their resources (time, money, computing power, etc) before they accomplish anything useful.  In order to achieve that, one needs to identify the attackers about whom one is concerned, quantify their resources and define what would be considered a "useful accomplishment".

Comment: @eggyal wordjungle... my point being that the database doesn't make it more secure (well unless this is where your security is) but my point simply is that having them as files i'sent MORE unsafe..

Comment: Question might be more suitable for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Im kinda new here, I dont get what is wrong or how can I fix it. I hope Im not bothering anyone :S

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR  This is really dangerous. Don't do it unless you must.

If I were you, I would start with a threat analysis. What possible security hazards are there to retaining these images of id cards on your system? What could go wrong? What are you defending against?

1. Badguys might penetrate your system and steal them in bulk, and sell them to identity thieves.
2. Same as 1, but they will also steal table information and correlate it to your images.
3. Somebody might misuse or abuse a feature of your system to view one or a few images, and misuse the information they get as a result.
4. Somebody might commit fraud upon you by giving you stolen or forged id cards.
5. If you're handling payments, your system might fail a PCI audit and you'd be unceremoniously denied your payment-handling access.

You need to figure out which threats you're defending against as you construct a system to try to secure these very sensitive images. You also need to figure out who is allowed to see this information, how you authenticate those authorized users, and how long you retain this information.

Ideally, you would not collect this information at all.

If you do collect it, use https:// from day one.

If you do have to collect it, your next best alternative is to inspect it promptly and then securely erase it, so you don't build a great honeypot for thieves.

If you do have to retain it, your next best alternative is to move it promptly to an airgapped storage medium, and erase it from your online systems.  You could burn a CD-ROM every few days and hold an archive of them in a file cabinet, for example.

If you must retain this information online, you definitely want to write web programs that store it to a file system someplace else than the web root. When somebody wants to see an image, you definitely don't want simply to present an image url like

```
   https://honeypot.com/imgs/idcards/user2573551.png
```

and serve up a file from a directory. Instead you want a bit of software that doesn't take a user id as an explicit user id parameter. That is, you might present a URL like

```
   https://honeypot.com/myId.php
```

You might also want to read up on security tokens called "nonces" that inhibit various sorts of cross-site or saved-URL attacks.  WordPress happens to have a good nonce system you might be able to learn from.

Be careful, eh?

Comment: Rather than (or perhaps in addition to) airgapped storage, one could asymmetrically encrypt the data on the client-side and transmit/store only the cryptotext to/on the server.  The data could then be accessed offline using the secret/private key as & when required.